# function imshow() in matlab for class double

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Why is an image of class type double seen completely white when the function imshow is used in matlab?This seems to be the case with every image

Answer (score 8):

By default, `imshow` [expects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html) images of type `double` to be in the range `[0,1]`.

As a solution, you can do the following:

```
imshow(img, [])
```

This is [equivalent to](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#inputarg_DisplayRange):

```
imshow(img, 'DisplayRange',[min(img(:)) max(img(:))])
```

Alternatively you can manually normalize the image to the expected `[0,1]` range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [im2double](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/im2double.html):

```
imshow(im2double(I))
```

Comment: If the values are over 1 in your orginal image array, imshow will threat everthing as 1 (white color).